# An adapter for disconnecting the current after a particular period of time

Tags: timer, 555

I want to prepare an adapter which will discontinue the power supply after a particular period of time. The time period will be provided manually using a switch. The time periods are: continuous supply, 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours.

So, what will be a good way to disconnect the power after the given time?

Comment: What kind of power are we talking about?

Comment: Also worth mentioning if this should be anything precise, a 555 won't be very accurate and it's probably getting towards the upper end of the time possible.

Comment: An hour glass and an optical sensor to detect no-sand in the top section springs to mind when thinking about 555s in this application LOL

Comment: @Andyaka Great idea. On topic, kind of, take an accelerometer and measure the changes related to the earth-moon-sun constelation. It won't work probably  because of imprecise sensors but you should try.

Comment: Depending on your load, a pool pump timer, or a standard electronic timing switch with multiple presets should work.

Comment: How about an MCU with a real time clock and a relay, that's uhhh, in orbit, transmitting EMPs to disable the electronics?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 1 to 4 hour booster timer control: -

[image]

I think it should be easy to wire up and use.